# Bootstrap fixed navbar inside div

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

In [bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) they're able to "trap" a `.navbar-fixed-top` inside their `.bs-docs-example` div:

```
<div class="bs-docs-example bs-navbar-top-example">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="position: absolute;">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
        [...]
```

But if I do the same in my test page the navbar "escapes" the div and get fixed in the top of the body, not the top of the div. How it's the trick achieved?

Comment: is it the behaviour of the the left sidebar navbar on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar that you are wondering about?

Comment: Nop is the example under the title "Fixed to top" (and "Fixed to bottom") on the right. They all have the tag "Example" on them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok figured it out. The parent element container must have `position: relative`, and navbar must have `position: absolute`, that way if you attach either `.navbar-fixed-top` or `.navbar-fixed-bottom` it will get fixed relative to the parent element and NOT relative to the entire page. Yeah!

Comment: This worked for me, except that my div has overflow on it and the navbar does not scroll with it.  Did you contend with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar">...</nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

That works with built-in Bootstrap's CSS.